# Calling async method behind Singleton.Instance

Tags: c#, asynchronous, singleton, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a basic singleton class, but the singleton has an async method like so:

```
public sealed class AddInHandler
{
    private static readonly AddInHandler instance = new AddInHandler();

    static AddInHandler()
    {
    }

    AddInHandler()
    {
    }

    public static AddInHandler Instance
    {
        get { return instance.Value; }
    }

    public async Task<AvailableActions> GetAvailableActions(string carrierMnemonic)
    {
        // some code that uses await...
    }
}
```

If I try to use the async method via the singleton, e.g:

```
public async Task<Collection<CarrierInformation>> RetrieveAvailableCarriersAsync()
{
    // some await code here

    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        // ...
        var availableActions = await AddInHandler.Instance.GetAvailableActions(addIn.Name);
    }
}
```

Then I hit error.

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda
>   expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async'
>   modifier.

I'm expecting it's because the Instance property isn't async that I'm having this issue?  Is this correct, and is there a recommended best approach for resolving this?

Comment: Please show the full context for your call. You can only use `await` within an asynchronous function - either an async method, or an async lambda expression. I strongly suspect that's the problem.

Comment: I think it is complaining about the method wrapping this code var availableActions = await AddInHandler.Instance.GetAvailableActions(addIn.Name);. That method needs to be marked as async

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm expecting it's because the Instance property isn't async that I'm
>   having this issue?

No, you're simply missing the `async` modifier inside the lambda expressions declaration. The lambda itself has to be marked as `async` in order for the compiler to use `await` inside it:

```
await Task.Run(async () => 
{
    // ...
    var availableActions = await AddInHandler.Instance.GetAvailableActions(addIn.Name);
}
```

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) is pretty straight forward:

> Use the async modifier to specify that a **method, lambda expression, or
>   anonymous method** is asynchronous. If you use this modifier on a method
>   or expression, it's referred to as an async method.

Answer (score 2):

If you're calling

```
var availableActions = await AddInHandler.Instance.GetAvailableActions(addIn.Name);
```

in an expresion of type `new Action(() =>{});` then you need the async modifier.

```
new Action( async () =>
   {
      // some await code
   });
```